# Adding IDs on the fly to select query

Tags: sql-server

I am pulling certain `ID`s from

```
select [ID] into #temp_total from
(
    select [ID] from #temp_a
    union
    select [ID] from #temp_b
    union
    select [ID] from #temp_c
)
```

I want to add a few hardcoded `ID`s to `#temp_total`:

```
select [ID] into #temp_total from
(
    select [ID] from #temp_a
    union
    select [ID] from #temp_b
    union
    select [ID] from #temp_c
    union
    select ('123', '456', '789') as [ID]
)
```

But this does not work. What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: "this does not work" means it generates an error. ALWAYS provide the complete error message - all of it. You have too much rep to need reminding of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Table Value Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

`select ID from (values ('123'), ('456'), ('789')) x (ID)`

Answer (score 1):

Use a union:

```sql
SELECT [ID] INTO #temp_total FROM
(
    SELECT [ID] FROM #temp_a
    UNION
    SELECT [ID] FROM #temp_b
    UNION
    SELECT [ID] FROM #temp_c
    UNION
    SELECT '123' UNION ALL SELECT '456' UNION ALL SELECT '789'
)
```